# Freshbooks API Call from Django View

Tags: python, django, django-views, freshbooks-api

How to make a HTTPS call from inside a Django view? I am trying to call the freshbooks api from django view but failed to do so as it gives me the following error. Unable to find the server at https.

Kindly help.

Comment: It would help to see the code you already have.

Comment: As long as we're posting links: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the url you are trying to open. Might be your URL is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice to see what you have so far but you can always use python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) module